# Opening a portrait in LATEX

Tags: graphics

I have a text and I want to highlight it with a kind of portrait like in the below image:

[image]

I mean, instead of writing "Placeholder/Image" I want to add my text in that kind of window with possibly other color.

Is it possible to do that in LaTeX? and How?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Short answer: Yes.

Comment: jajaja right :) but How do you do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDITED to transition automatically to a `\parbox` if width exceeds 2in.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,xcolor}
\newcommand\specbox[3][black]{\bgroup%
  \color{#1}%
  \fboxsep=1.7ex\relax%
  \setstackgap{S}{1.3ex}%
  \setbox0=\hbox{\stackanchor{#2}{#3}}%
  \ifdim\wd0>2in\relax%
    \fbox{\Shortstack{{\parbox{2in}{\centering #2}} {%
    \rule{1.6in}{.5pt}} {\parbox{2in}{\centering #3}}}}%
  \else%
    \fbox{\Shortstack{{#2} {\rule{\dimexpr\wd0-1em}{.5pt}} {#3}}}%
  \fi%
\egroup}
\begin{document}
\specbox[red]{Placeholder}{Image}

\specbox[green!50!black]{This is a test of the EBS}{this is only a test}

\specbox[blue]{This is a test of the Emergency Broadcast System}
  {this is only a test}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Right ;), let me try that.

Comment: Why does it appears "long"? A mean like a rectangle instead of a square, Is it because the amount of words that I put?

Comment: @user162343 Yes.  If you want the words stacked, you could make the argument a `\parbox`.  If you always wanted it of a fixed width, then that is possible, too.  But you were too vague in your question, so I had to make some guesses as to your intent.  I may revise to show more possibilities.

Comment: Sorry :) for that, the thing is that I want it varies the length so that I can write a considerable amount of information please :)

Comment: @user162343 Please look at my revision that transitions to multiline if the text width is greater than 2in.

Comment: Good, just give me a second :)

Comment: Sorry for this but the problem now is that the rectangle just got wider not longer.

Comment: I think the problem is that the \parbox vary the height, not the width and I need both.

Comment: @user162343 As long as you are willing to specify the width manually, that can be easily done.  If you want the macro to automatically vary both the height and the width, what constraint do you wish to employ to guide any algorithm?

Comment: Well in fact I have already solve it, I just wrote inside the \parbox 10 inches instead of 2, so that it is more wider and the height is less than before thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

More than one way possible.

[image: texsxPlaceholder]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\newcommand{\placeholder}{%
    \framebox{\parbox{.9\linewidth}{\centering\huge\color{red!60!black}\itshape
    Placeholder\par
    \rule[.5ex]{.6\linewidth}{.8pt}\par
    Wombat
}}}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{figure}
    \placeholder
\end{figure}
\blindtext
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{figure}
\blindtext

\begin{figure}
    \missingfigure[figwidth=\linewidth]{A figure is missing here}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Let me just try that, right? Thnks

Comment: I liked the idea of the text that says "missing figure" but How does the \begin{figure} command acts because I have already wrote and it did nothing. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @user162343 The `figure` environment places everything inside it to a suitable place. Pleas have a look at a LaTeX introduction.

Comment: Right, the thing is that I thought that whenever I write something inside that command it would appear in the gray square that you drew :)

Comment: @user162343  Package `todonotes` draws that grey box. It wasn't me. ;-)

Comment: Good let me try again then ;) just a second.

Comment: Still the same, I have already used the packages and it seems that it recognized the space but it did nothing :(

Comment: @user162343 Completely lost now. Better to open a new question linking this answer.

Comment: Well, let me still trying with the other answer and if I can't I'll do right?, Can I let you know?

Comment: You can let me know, you don't have to. You can also ask a new question.